# Typoscript entryLevel change on specific pages

Tags: html, typoscript

hopefully you won't throw stones at me, currently trying to figure out how to work with typoscript, not coming form a web programming background this gives me a bit of a headache.

Basically this is the hierarchy used on the root level of the website, it's working fine but for a couple of pages, let it be 4-5 we would need to have the root of the menu one step lower, trying to read through the net it should be entryLevel = 2 rather than entryLevel = 1 but only for that specific pages.

I don't get the idea how to change the code so it will change only that single line for a number of pageids.

Hope this is understandable.

```
10 = HMENU
10 {
    entryLevel = 1
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        expAll = 1
        noBlur = 1
        wrap = <ul class="vertical menu" data-accordion-menu>|</ul>
        target = _top
        NO {
            stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
            wrapItemAndSub = li|/li
        }
        ACT
        ACT = 1
        ACT {
            allWrap = <li class="is-active">|</li>
        }
        IFSUB < .NO
        IFSUB = 1
        IFSUB {
            ATagParams = href="#" class="destination"
            subst_elementUid = 1
            wrapItemAndSub = <li><a href="#" class="toggle-section" title="Toggle section" style="display: none;"><span class="icon"></span><span class="visuallyhidden">Toggle section</span></a>|</li>


        }
        ACTIFSUB
        ACTIFSUB = 1
        ACTIFSUB < .IFSUB
    }
```

would something as silly as this be reasonable? Found some howTo on a website but not sure if this would be fine as an overwrite for that variable and if that's even helping the cause in the first place.

```
entryLevel = 1
[gobalVar = TSFE:id=421, TSFE:id=2141, TSFE:id=8787]
entryLevel =2
[global]
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Actually tried to figure out different ways and now ended up pretty much copy and pasting the typoscript controlling the side menu and creating an extension template, copy paste all the typoscript setups excluding the main meta.ts and including the copycat where only the entryLevel was changed to 2.

Works for me and I guess it's a clean way to get around the problem, without hassling on the script file itself.